# Calabash Android No element found for query: textView marked:

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash

I get the error No element found for query: textView marked:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temper incididunt'.

It shows up in the console with query("*"), but when I query("textView marked:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temper incididunt'") I get [].

My test won't pass but the text shows up in the console...

Is there a character limit or am I missing something?

Comment: You sure it is a textView? What do you for the query `query("* marked:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temper incididunt'")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's like all of my experience, you'll want to use:

```
query "TextView marked:'...'"
```

note the capital T on TextView because it's a class

Since I'm guessing the Lorem, ... is text, not id or description, you could use:

```
query "* text:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temper incididunt'"
```

I don't believe it should be an issue, but if for some reason *marked* doesn't accept strings that long, *text* should

Answer (score 1):

If the class of the view is not `TextView` but an extension of `TextView` you have to use:

```
query("TextView text:'...'")
```

A better approach would be to use * instead of `TextView` - the test won't fail even if the class of the field changes:

```
query("* text:'...'")
```

An even better approach would be to use `id` instead of text:

```
query("* id:'lorem_ipsum_view'")
```